# Git & GoogleDrive - External storage for repositories

Tags: git, google-drive-api, repository

- **What I'm trying to achieve:**

  I'd like to use some kind of cloud or any kind of free *online* storage and use it as my personal repository and storage for my personal projects.

  I'd like to be able to store some data (1-5 GB) and I'd like to use it also as git repository
- **What I'm using:**

  1. Ubuntu 14.04
  2. Google Drive
  3. Git
  4. Google drive ocamlfuse
- **What I've tried**:

  I've been reading about ***google-drive-ocamlfuse***, this tool allows you to *mount* the space of your Google Drive in your PC (in my case in Linux).

  Everything works fine but the speed of read/write in that mounted drive is very very slow, I make an ls and it takes like 20-30 seconds to get the response, and everytime I generate a new repo it takes like 5 minutes to finish (an empty repo).

---

- Have anyone tried something like this before with better results ?
- Is there someother better option to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried Dropbox? Its Linux support is much better than Google Drive and it should work the way you want it right out of the box (just put the repo inside the Dropbox folder).

Comment: @fstanis thanks for your idea, I've already work some times with Dropbox as external storage, the problem of dropbox is that only have 2 GB, anyway I'll try git there, maybe is fastest

Comment: While you initially get only 2 GB, you can easily get more (for free) through various ways (connecting Facebook/Twitter accounts, installing Mailbox etc.), most notably by referring your friends. I have almost 7 GB total space right now (for $0 per month).

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll check on that, Thanks!